# Why is the `ngIf` not to be able to hide one of the two arrays?

Tags: angular

**Aim:** to show a certain array if a certain value has been set

**Steps to reproduce**

Declare a two-dimensional array

```
arrays = [
      { id: 'a', name: ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'] },
      { id: 'b', name: ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'] }
];
```

In the App it is possible to click on two images. When the one is clicked `el` will be `a` and the other will result in `b`

Create two ngFor loops

```
<ul *ngFor="let arr of arrays">
  <a *ngIf="arr.id===el" (click)="aMethod(arr.name)">{{arr.name}}</a>
  <li *ngIf="arr.id===el" *ngFor="let arr2 of arr.name">
    <a (click)="aMethod(arr2)">{{arr2}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Expected outcome**

```
a1
a2
a3
a4
```

or

```
b1
b2
b3
b4
```

**Current outcome**

```
a1,a2,a3,a4
a1
a2
a3
a4

b1
b2
b3
b4
```

or

```
a1
a2
a3
a4

b1,b2,b3,b4
b1
b2
b3
b4
```

**Question**

Why is the `ngIf` not to be able to hide one of the two arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have multiple template bindings on one element. So you **can't** use both *ngIf and *ngFor on the same element. you can do this:

```
<ul *ngFor="let arr of arrays">
  <a *ngIf="arr.id === el" (click)="aMethod(arr.name)">{{arr.name}}</a>
  <li *ngIf="arr.id === el">
    <div *ngFor="let arr2 of arr.name">
      <a (click)="aMethod(arr2)">{{arr2}}</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now if the el is 'a' the results will be:

```
a1,a2,a3,a4
a1
a2
a3
a4
```

Because both *ngIf are true, but the 'b' will be hidden.

You can also use the **template** tag instead creating wrapper div:

```
<ul *ngFor="let arr of arrays">
  <a *ngIf="arr.id === el" (click)="aMethod(arr.name)">{{arr.name}}</a>
  <template [ngIf]="arr.id === el">
    <li *ngFor="let arr2 of arr.name">
      <a (click)="aMethod(arr2)">{{arr2}}</a>
    </li>
  </template>
 </ul>
```

And by the way you have a tag inside ul without li.

Answer (score 1):

What FunStuff said. You can work around using

```
<ng-container *ngIf="arr.id===el">
  <li *ngFor="let arr2 of arr.name">
</ng-container>
```